# getting sprite coordinates of mouse position java slick2D tiled map

Tags: java, coordinates, slick2d

How to get sprite coords of mouse position? Game engine Slick2d. Tiled map 16x16.

Camera

```
public class Camera {

public int x, y;

Object object;

public Camera(int x, int y)
{

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public void tick()
{
    if(object != null)
    {
        if(object instanceof Player)
        {
            Player player = (Player) object;

            this.x = player.getX() - Jail.getJail().gm.getWidth() / 2;
            this.y = player.getY() - Jail.getJail().gm.getHeight() / 2;
        }
        else if(object instanceof Item)
        {
            Item item = (Item) object;

            this.x = item.getX() - Jail.getJail().gm.getWidth() / 2;
            this.y = item.getY() - Jail.getJail().gm.getHeight() / 2;
        }
        else if(object instanceof Vector2)
        {
            Vector2 vector = (Vector2) object;

            this.x = (int) vector.getX() - Jail.getJail().gm.getWidth() / 2;
            this.y = (int) vector.getY() - Jail.getJail().gm.getWidth() / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Unknown object.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Camera null object.");
    }
}

public void setObject(Object object)
{
    this.object = object;       
}

public void setX(int x)
{
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y)
{
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX()
{
    return this.x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return this.y;
}
}
```

Mouse click

```
            for (int l = 0; l < Jail.itemlist.size(); ++l)
        {
             Item item = (Item)Jail.itemlist.get(l);


                jail.cam.setObject(new Vector2(Mouse.getEventX(), Mouse.getEventY()));

                System.out.println("Mouse x: " + jail.cam.getX() / 16);
                System.out.println("Mouse y: " + jail.cam.getY() / 16);

                System.out.println("Item x: " + item.getX() / 16);
                System.out.println("Item y: " + item.getY() / 16);

                if (item.mousePressed(this.jail, par1, par2))
                {
                    System.out.println("CLICK ON ITEM");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("CLICK NO ITEM");
                }

                jail.cam.setObject(jail.player);
        }
```

In different positions the player, different mouse coordinates. How to fix this?

Mouse x: 8
Mouse y: 5
Item x: 10
Item y: 10
Player x: 37
Player y: 23

Mouse x: 9
Mouse y: -5
Item x: 10
Item y: 10
Player x: 37
Player y: 13

Mouse x: -2
Mouse y: -5
Item x: 10
Item y: 10
Player x: 25
Player y: 13

Comment: you should embed the image to your post as links can get lost after time. Further your question should show a minimum of how you tried to solve it yourself

Comment: I do not have a rating, to insert the picture. 
I do not know how to do it, so I'm asking.

Comment: Please post your picture on imgur and link it here in the commends.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, could it be that your `Mouse.getEventX(), Mouse.getEventY()` gives you coordinates representing the mousePosition in the window. Whereas the player coordinates represent the position in the world, starting (0/0) to (tilesX*16/tilesY*16).

As I would need to see more of your code, maybe this [Slick2d translate to worldcoordinates](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27298/java-slick2d-how-to-translate-mouse-coordinates-to-world-coordinates) can help you.